# I cannot present View Controller on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am using the code below to present a view controller on iPad, and it works:

```
- (IBAction)restoreTapped:(id)sender{

    RestoreInfoViewController* restoreInfoViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RestoreInfoViewController"];
    restoreInfoViewController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:restoreInfoViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

On the iPhone, a black screen appears. And I am getting the following warning:

```
Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You should store this `RestoreInfoViewController* restoreInfoViewController ` as ivar because object is deallocated in a moment after is presenting.

Comment: what you have on the iPad ? split view, viewController, popover ?

Comment: I have viewController